# How can I disable, or partially disable, picking of a javafx subscene?

Tags: javafx, scene, picking

I'm running into an issue on a graph-browsing program that I am building. I have two JavaFX subscenes, one of which browses a very large graph (that is, the mathetmatical construct of a graph, not something simple like a line graph or pie graph; potentially several gigabytes) in a manner similar to a flight simulator. The other one contains a set of controls, which are always at fixed points on the screen.

The only problem that I am running into is, when I attempt to get a pick result from the main Scene, it always stops at the first SubScene (the heads-up display). I've checked PickResult.getIntersectedNode(), it is definitely the SubScene intercepting the pick.

I have attempted this (on both SubScenes, to be sure):

```
layer.setPickOnBounds(false);
```

But it has had no effect.

I suspect that some transparent portion of the layered SubScene is still demarcating the space as occupied. I am not certain of this.

How can I set a SubScene to be unpickable, while leaving its contents alone?

---

As an addendum for discussion, here is a sample of the method I created (in an experiment) to build a heads-up-display. This is before I switched it to simply return a pane. (The parameter "fillPaint" is consistently set to Color.TRANSPARENT).

```
/**
 * Creates a subscene of set parameters
 * 
 * @param scene
 *            primary scene (into which subscene is injected)
 */
private SubScene makeHeadsUpSubScene(Scene scene, Camera camera, Paint fillPaint,
        Node node) {
    Group root = new Group();

    PointLight light = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
    light.setTranslateX(50);
    light.setTranslateY(-300);
    light.setTranslateZ(-400);
    PointLight light2 = new PointLight(Color.color(0.6, 0.3, 0.4));
    light2.setTranslateX(400);
    light2.setTranslateY(0);
    light2.setTranslateZ(-400);

    String title = "Title Stand-in";
    boolean msaa = true;

    AmbientLight ambientLight = new AmbientLight(Color.color(0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
    node.setRotationAxis(new Point3D(2, 1, 0).normalize());
    node.setTranslateX(180);
    node.setTranslateY(180);
    root.getChildren().addAll(new Label(title), ambientLight, light, light2, node);

    SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root, 640, 480, true, msaa ? SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED : SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED);
    subScene.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    subScene.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    subScene.setFill(fillPaint);
    subScene.setCamera(camera);

    return subScene;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried subscene.setPickOnBounds(false); ?

I've ran into similar problems layering with stackpanes .. 

I believe that setting makes it to where the pixel point for that node needs to be opaque or the pick gets passed to the next node in parent..

Comment: As I said, I have. If that's the actual specification for the method, then I might have a problem somewhere else in my code.

As far as I can tell, though, when pick-on-bounds is true, it intersects geometric shape. Thus, what works for a Pane might not work for a SubScene, as you can't set the "shape" of a SubScene.

Comment: Looking again at the specification for SubScene, I may have a workaround available. If I keep the mobile field in a SubScene, but put all items in the Heads-Up in a Pane, then display the SubScene beneath the pane, it _might_ work. I'll try that out later.

Comment: What I was doing is as you said, use SubScene for the 3D content(with own camera),
Then adding that SubScene to a root "ContentPane" .. (stackpane)..
When I wanted HUD items I would add those to stackpane and all was fine... but the picking ;)

Comment: Just curious.. Did you set the fill of the problem Subscene to Transparent?

Comment: I believe I did. As you can see in the addendum above, the Background is set to be empty, and fillPaint is set to Color.TRANSPARENT. The only possibility to come to mind is that I'm misinterpreting how setting fill color works.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that SubScene takes on the shape of its contents, which generally default to a complete and filled rectangle.

However, If SubScene is used for the field navigation, providing it with its own camera; while a simple Pane is used for the Heads-Up; it is possible to pick from both. Pick-on-bounds must of course be set to false for all appropriate panels.

Comment: Also I have been working on a HUD pane that attaches itself to the Camera directly .. though it is not meant for interaction it works well for displays..

Comment: Yes, it works well for me, too. The only time I bumped into an issue with stacking subscenes was when I attempted to pick.

Comment: glad you got it goin!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that to call `setFill(null)` on `subScene`

Setting with a color, even a transparent color, will cause the `subScene` to be 'picked' if it lays between the camera and the scene.